# EditText is covered by android device keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have an `EditText` in my mobile application for posting comments.

And the problem is when i click on the `EditText` for typing the message then the android soft keyboard is covered the half of the `EditText`.
I have already used the `android:windowSiftInputmode` functionality but not getting the expected result

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
```

plese see the attached images

[image: image of comments with EditText]

[image: image when keyboard is open]

Comment: Try to replace adjustPan to adjustResize.

Comment: try code in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android

Comment: u can try using scrollview instead of linear layout...hence, when the keyboard comes up, user can scroll the edittext upwards

Comment: @Haresh: thanks it works in the case of linear layout but i have this problem at other place also where i have used scrollview and there it is not working

Comment: Try this : android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"